# Check maximum value from colomns of table ,table colomn is not known/constant

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I was asked this question in an interview ,i already know we can use CASE /greatest function of oracle.
but interviewer wanted an answer where we dont have to change query if new column  is added.
e.g

```
Student English history maths 
zzzz    85      55     66
yyyy    47      99     55
```

result expected :-

```
zzzzz English :85
yyyyy history :99
```

now if table is altered same query should work

```
Student English history maths science
zzzz    85      55       66    86
yyyy    47      99       55    11
```

result expected :-

```
zzzzz science :86
yyyyy history :99
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the answer in Oracle using unpivot:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY student ORDER BY total DESC ) AS rn
  FROM   your_table
  UNPIVOT ( total FOR subject IN ( english, maths, history ) ) t
)
WHERE  rn = 1;
```

But you would need to add the new column name to the `IN` clause of the `UNPIVOT`.

However, if you were to use dynamic SQL then you could build that part of the query using the data dictionary (i.e. the `USER_TAB_COLUMNS` table):

```
DECLARE
  column_names CLOB;
  sql          CLOB;
BEGIN
  SELECT LISTAGG(
           column_name,
           ','
         ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY column_id )
  INTO   column_names;
  FROM   user_tab_columns
  WHERE  table_name  = 'YOUR_TABLE'
  AND    column_name <> 'STUDENT';

  sql := 'SELECT * FROM ( SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY student ORDER BY total DESC ) AS rn FROM your_table UNPIVOT ( total FOR subject IN ( ' || column_names || ' ) ) t ) WHERE  rn = 1;'

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle you can do this without `case`. Unpivot and sort data:

```
select student, subject, result 
  from (select student, subject, result, 
               rank() over (partition by student order by result desc) rnk
          from t
          unpivot (result for subject in (english, history, maths, science)))
  where rnk = 1
```

Demo:

```
with t(student, english, history, maths, science) as (
  select 'zzzz', 85, 55, 66, 86 from dual union all
  select 'yyyy', 47, 99, 55, 11 from dual )
select student, subject, result 
  from (select student, subject, result, 
               rank() over (partition by student order by result desc) rnk
          from t
          unpivot (result for subject in (english, history, maths, science)))
  where rnk = 1

STUDENT SUBJECT     RESULT
------- ------- ----------
yyyy    HISTORY         99
zzzz    SCIENCE         86
```

Anyway you have to list subjects in unpivot clause. To omit this you have to use [dynamic sql](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/dynamic.htm#LNPLS01101).

Answer (score 1):

You could unpivot the table by bouncing it through an XML structure:

```
create table scores (student, english, history, maths) as
select 'zzzz', 85, 55, 66 from dual
union all select 'yyyy', 47, 99, 55 from dual;

select x.student,
  max(x.subject) keep (dense_rank last order by x.score) as subject,
  max(x.score) as score
from (
  select dbms_xmlgen.getxml('select student, ''' || column_name || ''' as subject, '
    || column_name || ' as score from ' || table_name) as xml_clob
  from user_tab_columns
  where table_name = 'SCORES'
  and column_name != 'STUDENT'
) t
cross join xmltable (
  '//ROWSET/ROW'
  passing xmltype(t.xml_clob)
  columns student varchar2(8) path 'STUDENT',
    subject varchar2(30) path 'SUBJECT',
    score number path 'SCORE'
) x
group by x.student;

STUDENT  SUBJECT                             SCORE
-------- ------------------------------ ----------
yyyy     HISTORY                                99
zzzz     ENGLISH                                85
```

After altering the table to add the extra columns:

```
alter table scores add (science number);
update scores set science = 86 where student = 'zzzz';
update scores set science = 11 where student = 'yyyy';
```

the same query gets:

```
STUDENT  SUBJECT                             SCORE
-------- ------------------------------ ----------
yyyy     HISTORY                                99
zzzz     SCIENCE                                86
```

---

The innermost part of that generates the XML, with each student/column name/value converted to an element:

```
select dbms_xmlgen.getxml('select student, ''' || column_name || ''' as subect, '
  || column_name || ' as score from ' || table_name)
from user_tab_columns
where table_name = 'SCORES'
and column_name != 'STUDENT';

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ROWSET>
 <ROW>
  <STUDENT>zzzz</STUDENT>
  <SUBECT>ENGLISH</SUBECT>
  <SCORE>85</SCORE>
 </ROW>
...
```

The XMLTable then converts that back to relational data:

```
select x.*
from (
  select dbms_xmlgen.getxml('select student, ''' || column_name || ''' as subject, '
    || column_name || ' as score from ' || table_name) as xml_clob
  from user_tab_columns
  where table_name = 'SCORES'
  and column_name != 'STUDENT'
) t
cross join xmltable (
  '//ROWSET/ROW'
  passing xmltype(t.xml_clob)
  columns student varchar2(8) path 'STUDENT',
    subject varchar2(30) path 'SUBJECT',
    score number path 'SCORE'
) x;

STUDENT  SUBJECT                             SCORE
-------- ------------------------------ ----------
zzzz     ENGLISH                                85
yyyy     ENGLISH                                47
zzzz     HISTORY                                55
yyyy     HISTORY                                99
zzzz     MATHS                                  66
yyyy     MATHS                                  55
zzzz     SCIENCE                                86
yyyy     SCIENCE                                11
```

and then it's just an aggregation question...